# Writing a C# synch app using USB

Tags: c#, usb, communication, transfer

I'm looking at adding synch functionality to one of my C# applications. The intention is that 1 of the synch options is allowing one version of the app to synch to another version of the app via a USB cable.

The app is cross platform and implemented on Windows and Mac right now using Mono but will ultimately be ported to iOS and Android too.

All I want to do is send and receive data over a USB cable.

Does this sound like something that is feasible?

Comment: Please see the FAQ for information regarding the types of questions to ask here.

Comment: I feel there hasn't been any research done here. We're here to guide people having specific errors, not answer 'what should I do?' questions.

Comment: Incorrect, I did quite a bit of research but I didn't manage to find anything that discussed PC to PC data transfer over USB only PC to Device so I wondered if it was feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feasible? Sure. It's just a serial data transfer. You'll have to deal with the opening and closing of ports and the sending/receiving of data, but it's very straightforward.

```
public void SendDataOverSerial(string data) {
  try {
     SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 
     port.Open(); 
     port.Write(data); 
  }
  finally {
     port.Close();    
  }
}
```

Obviously you would need something on the other end of the pipe that received the data and did whatever it is that it should do with it.

Comment: I guess the bit I'm struggling with is doing it over USB, your example talks about COM1 which is a serial port. Presumably you're suggesting it's possible open a USB port as if it's a serial port?

Comment: If `port` is null or in an invalid state in the finally block it will throw an exception, which is something you shouldn't do. Probably better to use `using` in this case

Comment: USB is a serial protocol. It isn't COM, but the fundamentals are the same. Pick one of the coms libraries for USB (http://code.google.com/p/csharp-usb-hid-driver/, http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx, whatever) and code it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I recently wrote a blog post describing how to achieve this. Simply using something like SharpUSBLib wouldn't work because your iOS app can't access the USB port directly.

http://thecodewash.blogspot.com/2017/05/communicating-with-your-ios-app-over.html

To answer your question (so this answer isn't just a link), yes it definitely is possible to achieve this utilizing the USB Multiplexing Daemon (usbmuxd) program that is usually installed as part of iTunes. This program can create a socket connection to your iOS device through the USB cable, and allow you to communicate via that socket connection like you would any other socket. The link goes into much more detail.

Hope this helps!